# Background eclipse drawable

Tags: android, eclipse, background, drawable

I'm finishing my first app with Eclipse, and I'm wondering.

I got a background in my map "drawable-hdpi".

Now, my question is:

Do I need to resize it too, to the other drawable maps? or will Eclipse automaticly resize them when another device with a different resolution opens my app?

Ty :)

Comment: What platform are you asking about? SWT? Swing? JavaFX, Android?

Comment: Eclipse + app = android.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually provide seperate drawables for xxhdpi,xhdpi and mdpi (ldpi is deprecated). Eclipse does not automatically generate these bitmaps, and will most likely strech your image (best case scenario) or your entire layout will mess up (worst case scenario)

Comment: What size would they be? The background in hdpi is 271x400

Comment: Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html